# Where to install programs

Tags: directory

I understand that I have the `/computer/usr/share` path as well as the `/computer/opt` path. I noticed sometimes, like with programs such as Google Chrome and Teamviewer, they automatically installed themselves in my `/computer/opt` directory. However, for programs such as VSCode, I had to manually move the tar.gz file into my `/opt` directory, and then extract there. Why do some programs do this automatically, while others have to be done manually?

Also, when installing programs, what is the best directory to install them in? (i.e. what is the Linux equivalent to Program Files (x86) for Windows?)

Thank you.

Comment: Perhaps this link will help:  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LinuxFilesystemTreeOverview .  I have to admit that I don't know where your `/computer` comes from.  `/usr` and `/opt` should be off of the root directory.

Comment: @Ray `name@name-myComputer:~$` this is what shows up when I first open the terminal. Is this my root path?

Comment: Uh, no.  Your root directory is `/`.  I think that link I sent to you mentions that.  The prompt is the default prompt (yes, you can change it).  It just says that your login name is `name` and the name of your computer is `name-myComputer`.  The `~` is your "home directory" -- the highest directory for a user.  You can type `pwd` to find out what is the current directory.    I guess I'm getting a bit off-topic.  If anything I've said sounds confusing, perhaps you should look for tutorials on navigating through directories?

Comment: @Ray when I open the terminal and type `pwd` it says " / ". So does that mean I am in root by default? I'm sorry, this stuff is sort of confusing to me.

Comment: This post explains about the  installation folders in ubuntu (or linux in general)-    [Where are programs installed](http://askubuntu.com/questions/150611/how-to-tell-ubuntu-where-to-install-a-program-and-how-to-tell-where-an-existing)

Comment: @dhaneku.b If you log in, open a terminal, and type `pwd` and it says `/`, that probably means you don't have a home directory.  Take a look at this http://askubuntu.com/questions/374870/home-directory-not-being-created or look for others asking about the lack of a home directory.  You don't need to say sorry, but you might want to invest some time into a proper tutorial instead of a Q&A board like askubuntu.  Just a suggestion since you seem to have many questions and you're drifting away from your original question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is no `C:\Program Files\` in linux "per se". Therefore it doesn't exist one single (default) place where programs where to install. Actually many linux programs installs all over the place, parts of them installs in different folders. That's happening for performance optimization - one of many reasons why linux runs faster than Windows.

Best practice is to allow the program to install wherever it wants. Don't worry about volume fragmentation. That's virtually non-existent in linux.

The same thing happens in Windows too, when some big programs are installing files in ProgramData or CommonFiles folders. I've seen programs installing in Program Files (x64) and their respective Licence Key Server installing in Program Files (x86). Many specific user data may install in `C:\Users\Documents\`.

When a program uses many per-user options and files, it ussually installs to `/usr/share`. When it does not, it ussually installs to `/opt`. You could say that `/usr` is the equivalent of Users folder from Windows. `/opt` stands for optional software (that doesn't come bundled with the Ubuntu original disk).

For in-depth details of where and how linux programs are installed, please see this topic: [Where are my installed applications](https://askubuntu.com/questions/9024/where-are-my-installed-applications)

There is no single Program Files because of security reasons. Trusted applications (verified by the Software Center) may install in more sensitive places like `/bin` (=binaries) or even `/sbin` (=superbinaries), while untrusted (unverified) apps are installed in secure and secluded locations like `/opt`.

Comment: Can you elaborate what is this "performance optimization" that makes Linux run faster than Windows?

Comment: "All over the place" is misleading. there is a structure, an order to this, and its well documented. It is called FHS Filesystem Hierarchy Standard see this:
https://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs-3.0.pdf  it'll tell you about the organization, and motivation to the linux structure, as well as where to put what types of files exactly.

Comment: In j0h's source section 3.16. it says `sbin` stands for `System binaries` not `superbinaries`